# nginx loadbalancer is redirecting to the wrong port

Tags: nginx, load-balancing, port

I am trying to get the nxinx load balancer to work. I have the following configuration:

```
upstream backend {
  server app-1.example.com:8001 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=60s;
  server app-2.example.com:8001 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=60s;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name app.example.com;

  access_log /var/log/nginx/app/access.log combined;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/app/error.log;

  location / {
    include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
    proxy_pass http://backend;
  }

}
```

where `/etc/nginx/proxy_params` is the default:

```
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
```

When the load balancer gets a redirect (as some of the pages on the site will do), it includes port 8001 in the redirect, e.g. `http://app.example.com:8001/some/url` instead of `http://app.example.com/some/url`.

How can I fix this? I've tried setting `proxy_redirect` to `off`, but it has no effect.

Comment: This sounds like your application is causing the problem.

Comment: @MichaelHampton  Can you be more specific? Is there some header that the application should be sending?  From a web search, this seems like a common problem with nginx, but none of the suggested solutions appear to work.

Comment: nginx doesn't generate the redirects, your application does. Therefore it's most likely generating incorrect redirects.

Comment: Try this:  [Nginx solution for Apache ProxyPassReverse](http://wiki.nginx.org/LikeApache).  Not putting this as an answer because I'm far too lazy to elaborate on this.

Comment: @MichaelHampton The application is redirecting as if the user agent is connected directly to it, which is what the application should be doing. nginx is rewriting the Location headers in redirects, but it is not changing the port.  So it seems that the problem is nginx or how it is configured.